# RETURN 1-7 iso day NUMBER of week in a function

Tags: oracle, function, date

I could use a bit of help. I'm trying to CREATE a function that returns 1-7 where 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday… 7=Sunday.

I know that 18-JUL-2022 is a Monday and I expect the NUMBER 1 to be returned. Yet I'm getting back 29?

How can I CREATE a function that will RETURN 1-7 only. Why am I getting back 29?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2022-07-18' ,'IW') FROM DUAL 
29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'iw'` in `to_char(<date>)` is the ISO week number (in the year), not the day number within the ISO week.

Unfortunately, for reasons known only to Oracle, they don't offer a simple date function to return the ISO day of the week.

As a workaround, the same `'iw'` option in a different function, `'trunc(<date>)'`, is helpful in your problem; it truncates the date to the beginning of the ISO week (the Monday of the week, at midnight). Why `'iw'` means such different things in two different date functions, only the brilliant developers at Oracle can tell us.

So, you would have to do something a bit tedious, like this (showing it for dates that also have non-zero time-of-day); using a `with` clause just to generate a bit of testing data:

```
with
  sample_data (dt) as (
    select to_date('2021-03-04 22:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select to_date('2022-05-30 10:28', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') from dual
  )
select to_char(dt, 'Dy dd-Mon-yyyy')   as dt,
       trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') + 1 as iso_day_of_week
from   sample_data
;

DT                      ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK
----------------------- ---------------
Thu 04-Mar-2021                       4
Mon 30-May-2022                       1
```

WARNING: `to_char(<date>)` has an option to show the "day-of-week" - but that is useless to you, since it returns the day-of-week in the locale encoded in NLS settings, not the standard "ISO day of the week" you said you need.

**EDIT** - per OP's request, here is how the same can be wrapped within a PL/SQL function that can be called from SQL. Note the `pragma udf` directive (available since Oracle 12) - it makes the code more efficient when the function is called in a SQL context.

```
create or replace function iso_day_of_week(dt date)
  return number
  deterministic
as
  pragma udf;
begin
  return trunc(dt, 'iw') - trunc(dt) + 1;
end;
/
```

Testing the same on the sample data from above:

```
with
  sample_data (dt) as (
    select to_date('2021-03-04 22:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select to_date('2022-05-30 10:28', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') from dual
  )
select to_char(dt, 'Dy dd-Mon-yyyy') as dt,
       iso_day_of_week(dt)           as iso_day_of_week
from   sample_data
;

DT                      ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK
----------------------- ---------------
Thu 04-Mar-2021                       4
Mon 30-May-2022                       1
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Can my request be easily wrapped into a function, which I can give to my QA team? As I mentioned, I just want to pass a date or timestamp and RETURN a 1-7

Comment: @Pugzly - yes, easily. I will edit my answer to add that.

Answer (score -2):

'IW' returns week of the year, you need 'D' for the day of the week.
Depending on NLS settings, it will return 1 or 2 for Monday.

Comment: The 'D' for day of the week does not return the ISO day of the week. The OP said explicitly he needed Monday = 1, and his attempted use of IW confirms that he needs the ISO definition, not the locale-specific one.

Comment: Then he can use something like this

select case to_char(date '2022-07-24', 'DY') 
       when 'MON' then 1
       when 'TUE' then 2
       when 'WED' then 3
       when 'THU' then 4
       when 'FRI' then 5
       when 'SAT' then 6
       else 7
       end 
  from dual;

Comment: I'm looking for something independent of the NLS settings

Comment: Depending on the territory, `TO_CHAR(date_value, 'D')` will either return 1 (if you are in Europe, etc.), 2 (if you are in America), 3 (if you are in the Middle East) or 4 (if you are in Bangladesh).